# Is it possible to call one class function from another class object without inherit the first class

Tags: c++

```
Class A
{

    Protected:
    A();
    public:
    void function1();
};
class B
{

    public:
    B();
    void function2();
};

void main()
{

    B b;
    b.function1();
    b.function2();//How can I call this function using second class object.

}
```

Can anyone suggest me there is anyway to do this.

Comment: Since `function1` is not a member of the class `B` you simply can't call it though the `b` object, you need an object instance of the `A` class. Can you please expand on what the *real* problem is? What are you really trying to do? Right now this is to much of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is to make `A` class constructor public and then you can use `A` object through composition:

```cpp
class A {
 public:
  A() = default;
  void function1() {
   cout << "function 1\n"; 
  }
};

class B {
 public:
  B() = default;
  void function2() {
    cout << "function 2\n";
  }
  A a;
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.function2();
    b.a.function1();
    return 0;
}
```